# Can i use Java swing application in a freshly installed Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing

Do the big Linux distributions support java when freshly installed?
If i have a Java Swing application, will it work in a freshly installed Linux with no internet connection?

I understand that there are no guarantees, but how likely is it for a Linux machine NOT to have any java/Swing support?

Comment: if there is no jre installed, it's very likely.

Comment: It's *very* likely **not** to have Java support. Java is not necessary for the operating system's operation, and there's no reason to install automatically something that might not be used at all. That's at least the case with Ubuntu (which is still the most popular desktop Linux I believe).

Answer (score -1):

if you can check the o/p of command `java -version` in a terminal, it'll show if you have java installed or not.

So if Java or JRE is installed you can surely use your Swing application.

But if you are planning to develop a swing app you need to have JDK installed in your system.
you can if the command `javac -version` is working then you have JDK installed in your system.

But I suspect if any Linux distribution comes pre-installed with a JDK. For once you can find installed JRE by default but it is difficult to get pre-installed JDK in any Linux OS.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes, but the failure of `javac -version` does not indicate that java is not installed. It only indicates that it is not found in any directory in the current PATH.

Comment: yes but its the most standard & easiest way to detect whether you are having JDK on your system or not..
& i also have mentioned about JRE..